# Pull docker hub images in Helm chart values.yaml

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, dockerhub

I'm new to helm and Kubernetes world.
I'm working on a project using Docker, Kubernetes and helm in which I'm trying to deploy a simple Nodejs application using helm chart on Kubernetes.

Here's what I have tried:

**From `Dockerfile`:**

```
FROM node:6.9.2
EXPOSE 30000
COPY server.js .
CMD node server.js
```

I have build the image, tag it and push it to the docker hub repository at: `MY_USERNAME/myhello:0.2`

Then I run the simple commad to create a helm chart as:
`helm create mychart`
It created a mychart directory witll all the helm components.

Then i have edited the `values.yaml` file as:

```
replicaCount: 1
image:
  repository: MY_USERNAME/myhello
  tag: 0.2
  pullPolicy: IfNotPresent

nameOverride: ""
fullnameOverride: ""

service:
  type: NodePort
  port: 80
  externalPort: 30000

ingress:
  enabled: false
  annotations: {}
    # kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    # kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
  paths: []
  hosts:
    - chart-example.local
  tls: []
  #  - secretName: chart-example-tls
  #    hosts:
  #      - chart-example.local

resources: {}
  # We usually recommend not to specify default resources and to leave this as a conscious
  # choice for the user. This also increases chances charts run on environments with little
  # resources, such as Minikube. If you do want to specify resources, uncomment the following
  # lines, adjust them as necessary, and remove the curly braces after 'resources:'.
  # limits:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi
  # requests:
  #  cpu: 100m
  #  memory: 128Mi

nodeSelector: {}

tolerations: []

affinity: {}
```

After that I have installed the chart as:
`helm install --name myhelmdep01 mychart`

and when run `kubectl get pods` 
it shows the `ErrImagePull`

I have tried with by mentioning the image name as : `docker.io/arycloud/myhello`
in this case the image pulled successfully but there's another error comes up as:

> Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.5:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.5:80: connect: connection refused

Answer (score 4):

Run `kubectl describe pod <yourpod>` soon after the error occurs and there should be an event near the bottom of the output that tells you exactly what the image pull problem is.

Off the top of my head it could be one of these options:

- It's a private repo and you haven't provided the service account for the pod/deployment with the proper imagePullSecret
- Your backend isn't docker or does not assume that non prefixed images are on hub.docker.com. Try this instead: `registry-1.docker.io/arycloud/myhello`

If you can find that error it should be pretty straight forward.

Comment: The repo is public, and here's at the bottom of `kubectl describe pod` : `Warning  Unhealthy  25s (x3 over 45s)  kubelet, minikube  Liveness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.4:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.4:80: connect: connection refused
  Warning  Unhealthy  8s (x5 over 48s)   kubelet, minikube  Readiness probe failed: Get http://172.17.0.4:80/: dial tcp 172.17.0.4:80: connect: connection refused`

Comment: That doesn't address the image pull problem. That seems to indicate that your container is running but is failing it's liveness/readiness probes. 

check this documentation: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/

Comment: did you manage to fix this?